# Convert formula to value once formula has calculated

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following VBA module to create a Timestamp UDF, which stamps the date once the referenced cell reads "Done":

```
Function Timestamp(Reference As Range)
    If Reference.Value = "Done" Then
        Timestamp = Format(Date, "ddd dd mmm")
    Else
        Timestamp = ""
    End If
End Function
```

The date stays the same even after refreshing / closing and opening the workbook as long as the referenced cell still reads "Done"; however if someone accidentally changes the referenced cell then the date is reset.

I need a VBA code to convert the formula to value once it has calculated, so the date will always stay the same.  The solution needs to be automatic rather than manual and I can't enable iterative formulas on this workbook because it's used by multiple users.  Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Worksheet Change event for that:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim AffectedCells As Range
    Set AffectedCells = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A"))  ' Range A:A is the range we observe for 'done'
    
    If AffectedCells Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In AffectedCells
        If Cell.Value = "done" Then
            Dim UpdateTimestamp As Boolean
            UpdateTimestamp = True
            
            If Range("B" & Cell.Row).Value <> vbNullString Then
                UpdateTimestamp = MsgBox("Timestamp exists do you want to update it?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes
            End If
            
            If UpdateTimestamp Then
                Me.Range("B" & Cell.Row).Value = Format$(Date, "ddd dd mmm")
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
    
End Sub
```

[image]

---

// Edit according comment:

If you want to check multiple ranges for different things you need to slightly change your code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range

    Dim ObservedRangeA As Range
    Set ObservedRangeA = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A"))  ' Range A:A is the range we observe for 'done'
    
    If Not ObservedRangeA Is Nothing Then
        For Each Cell In ObservedRangeA 
            If Cell.Value = "done" And Range("B" & Cell.Row).Value = vbNullString Then
                Me.Range("B" & Cell.Row).Value = Format$(Date, "ddd dd mmm")
            End If
        Next Cell
    End If

    Dim ObservedRangeB As Range
    Set ObservedRangeB = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C:C"))  ' Range C:C is the range we observe for ""
    
    If Not ObservedRangeB Is Nothing Then
        For Each Cell In ObservedRangeB 
            If Cell.Value = "" And Range("B" & Cell.Row).Value = vbNullString Then
                Me.Range("B" & Cell.Row).Value = Format$(Date, "ddd dd mmm")
            End If
        Next Cell
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Peh - thanks so much, this looks like the solution I might need.  2 questions - a) is there a way to expand this code to check different ranges for different values (e.g. one range check for "done", another range check if the cell is not blank) and create timestamps for each of them? b) is there a way to remove the message box, I don't want it to change the timestamp if one already exists?

Comment: @MattBoard See my edit, you can observe multiple ranges for different things.

Comment: That's amazing, thank you so much!  I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: @PEH apologies for slow response, marked at solved now. Thank you for all your help!